# Complex numbers inequalities and optimisation

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm now aware that you can't definitely with ease say that one complex number is greater than another. 
Though what about imaginary numbers? Is $5i > 3i$? Is $i>-i$?

Is it possible to optimise (find the minimum or maximum) of a complex number function? I assume if it's not ordered you can't do that ,as when we optimise for real numbers the question is if which is the greatest or least output. But if you can't say one output is greater than another than how would you optimise it?

Thanks

Comment: You usually compare the modulus of complex functions, so that you can then use the well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}$. Clearly this is not the only possible choice... you could choose any norm-like function you like to get some ordering. For example the value of the real part, or of the imaginary part.

Comment: Could you say what is the problem you have that necessitates a comparison of complex numbers ? It would may be help to hopefully give you other kinds of answer.

Comment: You are correct. It is meaningless to compare two imaginary numbers because there is no concept of order. On the other hand, if I were to assume that $5i>3i$, then we end up with $i>0$ which is utter nonsense for the same reason.

Comment: Well the reason I was using the imaginary numbers inequality in the question is because the real question is about the optimisation of complex number functions. How can I optimise it if there is no sense of one complex number being greater than another? If there is a greater modulus of one of the numbers does that mean it's greater than/less than (for min/max)?

Answer (score 0):

I Think we can't say that 5i>3i.
But if the modulus is greatest then we say the complex number is greater.|5i|=5 &|3i|=3. So we may say that 5i>3i. But it is true that we can't say that 5i>3i